# Program to tell if a number is even or odd. its sayng theres no previous 'if' before 'else'

Tags: c

I intended to make a program to make a program that tells the user if a given integer number is even or odd. However, it says that the 'else' has no previous 'if', what am I getting wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int num;

printf("type an integer ");
scanf("%d", &num);

if(num % 2 == 0);
    printf("%d is even", num);

else
    printf("%d is odd", num);

return 0;
}
```

There´s no output

Comment: Remove the `;` from the end of the `if` line. And get used to wrap *every* then block with curly brackets, it'll help you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code**

```
if(num % 2 == 0);
   printf("%d is even", num);
```

**The fix**

```
if(num % 2 == 0)
   printf("%d is even", num);
```

**The issue**

You have a semi-colon after your if statement, removing it will resolve your issue.